# Unity3d stretch GUI.Box

Tags: unity-game-engine

I newby to Unity and I write a simple tic-tac-toe game for mobile devices. 
I have troubles with GUI.Box. I try to make it stretch, but it does not work and text is clipped. My code:

```
GUIStyle lBoxStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.box);
lBoxStyle.stretchWidth = true;
lBoxStyle.stretchHeight = true;
lBoxStyle.wordWrap = true;
lBoxStyle.fontSize = 48;
lBoxStyle.normal.textColor = Color.black;
GUI.Box(new Rect((virtualWidth - mBoxWidth) / 2, (virtualHeight - mBoxHeight) / 2, mBoxWidth, mBoxHeight), mAlert, lBoxStyle);
```

How can I fix it?
Also how I can reduce size if text is short?

Comment: I'd recommend you download the latest beta version of Unity 5, they are making substantial changes to the GUI which includes this "stretch behaviour" by default...

Comment: @Lefty thanks for your advice, but I can not use Unity 5 because of my company rules :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out what is the size of the content with `CalcSize`. Then use that size to make the box tightly fitted around the content.

```
    GUIStyle lBoxStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.box);
    lBoxStyle.stretchWidth = true;
    lBoxStyle.stretchHeight = true;
    lBoxStyle.wordWrap = true;
    lBoxStyle.fontSize = 48;
    lBoxStyle.normal.textColor = Color.Black;

    // Caculate the size of the content
    Vector2 size = lBoxStyle.CalcSize(new GUIContent(mAlert));

    // Padding if needed
    // size += new Vector2(10, 10)

    // Use the size as the size of the element
    GUI.Box(new Rect((virtualWidth - size.x) / 2, (virtualHeight - size.y) / 2, size.x, size.y), mAlert, lBoxStyle);
```